# How to sort selected items to the top of the list for react-select Async

Tags: react-select

My use case calls for sorting options so selected items are at the top of the list. I was able to accomplish this for the Select component using the `onChange` event. This same pattern doesn't seem to work for the Async component because of how the `loadOptions` feeds options into the menu list.

I've created an example on CodeSandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-05orp2?file=/example.tsx

The code snippet looks like this:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";
import Select from "react-select";
import { options as baseOptions } from "./options";

const filterColors = (inputValue: string) => {
  return baseOptions.filter((i) =>
    i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
  );
};

const loadOptions = (inputValue: string, callback: (options) => void) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(filterColors(inputValue));
  }, 1000);
};

export default () => {
  /** Select Options */
  const initialOptions = useRef(baseOptions);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(initialOptions.current);

  function onSelectChange(newOptions, action) {
    const stateOptions =
      initialOptions.current?.filter((option) => {
        return !newOptions.find((newOpt) => {
          return newOpt === option;
        });
      }) ?? [];
    const updatedOptions = newOptions?.concat(stateOptions);
    setOptions(updatedOptions);
  }

  /** Async Options */
  const [asyncOptions, setAsyncOptions] = useState(initialOptions.current);

  function onAsyncChange(newOptions, action) {
    const stateOptions =
      initialOptions.current?.filter((option) => {
        return !newOptions.find((newOpt) => {
          return newOpt === option;
        });
      }) ?? [];
    const updatedOptions = newOptions?.concat(stateOptions);
    setAsyncOptions(updatedOptions);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label>Select</label>
      <Select
        isClearable
        isMulti
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        onChange={onSelectChange}
        options={options}
      />

      <label>Async</label>
      <AsyncSelect
        loadOptions={loadOptions}
        defaultOptions
        isMulti
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        onChange={onAsyncChange}
        options={asyncOptions}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Given an initial list of options that are sorted Option 1, Option 2, Option 3, Option 4
The output looks like this:
**Select Component**
[image: An image of the Select component with properly sorted selected items at the top of the menu.]

**Async Component** Notice the selected value are not, but should be sorted with the selected items at the top of the list.
[image: An image of the Async component options which doesn't sort the selected values to the top of the list.]

As noted in the code sandbox, I've tried sorting the `Async` component options the same way I did the `Select` options using the `onChange` event.  This however doesn't work and it seems the paradigm for the `Async` component is difference since it performs callbacks.

I'd like to have the selected options appear at the top of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a work around for this by sorting the selected values using a custom `MenuList` component.

**Code Sandbox Example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-async-sort-selected-working-ex3oug

**Example Code**

```
import React from "react";

import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";
import { options as baseOptions } from "./options";

const filterOptions = (inputValue: string) => {
  return baseOptions.filter((i) =>
    i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
  );
};

const loadOptions = (inputValue: string, callback: (options) => void) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(filterOptions(inputValue));
  }, 1000);
};

export default () => {
  /** Select Options */
  const options = [...baseOptions];

  /** Async Options */
  // const [asyncOptions, setAsyncOptions] = useState(initialOptions.current);
  function MenuList(props) {
    if (props.isLoading) {
      return <components.MenuList {...props} />;
    }
    const selectedOptions =
      props.children?.filter?.((childNode) => childNode.props.isSelected) ?? [];
    const nonSelectedOptions =
      props.children?.filter?.((childNode) => !childNode.props.isSelected) ??
      [];
    const childrenToRender = [...selectedOptions, ...nonSelectedOptions];
    return (
      <components.MenuList {...props}>{childrenToRender}</components.MenuList>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label>Select</label>
      <Select
        isClearable
        isMulti
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        options={options}
        components={{ MenuList }}
      />

      <label>Async</label>
      <AsyncSelect
        loadOptions={loadOptions}
        defaultOptions
        isMulti
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        components={{ MenuList }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```